# How to use react-draft-wysiwyg in css-modules?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using editor of react-draft-wysiwyg in my project and using css-modules for server-side rendering but unable include the styles of editor with css-modules.any help or suggestion will be appreciated